# Formik Typescript - Argument of type 'FC<IProps>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'CompositeComponent<object & FormikSharedConfig<{}>

Tags: reactjs, typescript, formik, react-typescript

I am trying to add formik to my react hooks component with a "withFormik" HOC but i am getting error

> Argument of type 'FC' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'CompositeComponent<object & FormikSharedConfig<{}> &
> FormikState & FormikHelpers &
> FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps<...> & FormikRegistration & {
> ...; }>'.   Type 'FunctionComponent' is not assignable to type
> 'StatelessComponent<object & FormikSharedConfig<{}> &
> FormikState & FormikHelpers &
> FormikHandlers & FormikComputedProps<...> & FormikRegistration & {
> ...; }>'.

Here is my code below for the same

```
import React from "react";

//Libraries import........
import { Form, Input, Button, Checkbox } from "antd";
import { FormikProps, FormikValues, useFormik, withFormik } from "formik";
import styles from "./login.module.scss";
import * as Yup from "yup";
//Components import........

interface FormValues {
  email: string;
}

interface IProps extends FormikProps<FormValues> {}

const Login: React.FC<IProps> = (props) => {
  const { handleSubmit, handleBlur, handleChange, handleReset } = props;

  return (
    <Form
      name="basic"
      labelCol={{ span: 8 }}
      wrapperCol={{ span: 16 }}
      onSubmitCapture={handleSubmit}
      autoComplete="off"
    >
      <Form.Item label="Username" name="email">
        <Input />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item label="Password" name="password">
        <Input.Password />
      </Form.Item>

      <Form.Item wrapperCol={{ offset: 8, span: 16 }}>
        <Button type="primary" htmlType="submit">
          Submit
        </Button>
      </Form.Item>
    </Form>
  );
};

export const LoginView = withFormik({
  mapPropsToValues: (props) => ({ email: "", password: "" }),
  validationSchema: Yup.object({
    email: Yup.string().required(),
  }),
  handleSubmit: (values) => {
    console.log(values);
  },
})(Login);
```

So my ("Login") on hover is giving this error

Also my code is running fine it seems with no issue, but i do get this error in my VS Code.

Any help is appreciated thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add description props to your `withFormik<MyFormProps, FormValues>(){...}`

```
interface FormProps {
    email: string;
    password: string;
}

interface FormValues {
    email: string;
}

export const LoginView = withFormik<FormProps, FormValues>(){...}
```

ps. got the answer from docs example https://formik.org/docs/guides/typescript#withformik